# Avoid Hardcoding values in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to remove an element from associative array :

```
$.each(d.envlist,function(key,value) {
    $("#environment").find("option[value='staging']").attr('disabled','disabled');
    alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

Now the requirement is that I wish to pass a variable instead of hard-coding the 'staging' part in above code. 
It should be a  as printed in the alert.

How can I do this ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just concatenate variable with string: `.find("option[value='" + value + "']")`. FYI, you should use `.prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: So you're saying that the value you are looking for isn't the key or the value parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just export `'staging'` into a variable and concatenate it

```
var optionValue = 'staging';

$.each(d.envlist, function(key,value) {
    $("#environment").find("option[value='" + optionValue + "']")
        .attr('disabled','disabled');

         alert( key + ": " + value );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assemble a string variable with the desired value and then just insert it into the selector:

```
var environment = 'staging'; // change this according to your environment
...find("option[value='"+ environment +"']");
```

Perhaps a super simple ("hello world" style) example will help explain:

```
var name = 'ggwp';
alert( 'Hello' + name + ', how are you?' );
// Hello ggpw, how are you?
```

The `name` variable is inserted into the string used by the alert, so the final message that the user will see has the variable inside the string.

For your case, I would assume that this `environment` variable declaring whether you are running on stage/dev/production is used in multiple places within your code - to that end - I would recommend placing the initialization of this variable in a *global* kind of place so that all components and modules will have access to it. This way you will only need to change a variable in one place to change the applications environment.